# Algorithm improvement for tidy up

Tags: algorithm, optimization

Suppose you have a rectangle surface and some round/rectangle objects (different size).
I want to write an algorithm that will tidy up those objects on the surface.
I have to put a maximum objects on the same surface.
I think i will have to put biggest objects first and smallest then.
Do you know if there is a specific algorithm in order to optimize this ?
It is a kind of tetris resolution but i can choose order of pieces.

Thanks

Comment: Are you also considering the height here or only surface?

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of the different sizes / distribution of the given objects?

Comment: Guess you are not into homework  either

Answer (score 1):

Since you want maximise the number of objects you are going to place, a  greedy algorithm might work well in most of the cases:

```
      Sort boxes according to length(ascending order).
      Start from the smallest box:
      for every box : 
           try to place it in a already occupied row
           if not possible place it in a new row.
           if not possible to place - break; //since anything bigger than would not fit.
```

If you are considering height also, this is called [Packing Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems).
You can check related algorithms [here](http://cgi.csc.liv.ac.uk/~epa/surveyhtml.html)

Answer (score -1):

This is called the [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

EDIT:
It's actually a subtype of the Knapsack problem: [Bin Packing Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)

Comment: Knapsack problem has weights, this has nothing to do with knapsack problem.

Comment: Your _weight_ can also be a dimension

Comment: @karthik You're right, technically it's not a knapsack problem, but a subtype of it

Comment: but his objective is different. He wants to maximise the number of items. By the way, I did not downvote you.